# How to create a cron log file in macOS High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, logs, cron

I have an issue with `cron` in macOS High Sierra.

I have cron running, and it is running the jobs I want to run. I am unable, however, to figure out how to make it create a `cron.log` file in `/var/log`.

I've edited `/etc/syslog.conf` file by adding:

`cron.*      /var/log/cron.log`

and relaunched the syslog daemon, but I still do not get a log file.

I've edited the `com.vix.cron.plist` file and redirected output and error messages to `/var/log/cron.log`. Even though that works, it is nowhere near being a proper log file with date and time shown.

Comment: Have you added any `debugflags` to `cron` ?

Comment: I've added -x misc, if that's what you mean, in the .plist file.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You can add multiple flags but I'm not sure if that will help you reach your goal.

Comment: All I need is the date and time, so that I am sure the command is run on schedule.

Comment: Wrap your command in a shell script that prints the date and time to the log file, then runs the command and finally print something to the log file again.

Comment: If I were to do that, I could just run the script file from cron or from launchd and have the script file do all the work. There should be a simpler way to get a proper cron.log file!